# How to check or setup view template extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

I have jbuilder file:

```
app/views/api/items/show.json.jbuilder
```

code

```
render :show
#or
render :show, template: "api/items/show"
```

does not worked - `template is missing`, but code

```
render :show, template: "api/items/show.json"
```

worked fine.

What is wrong? What need to check?
Which file to see or what to dump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the [`respond_to`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to) method to tell Rails you're responding to a `json` request.

```
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there way to set up it as default globally at least for each controller class? I write api only application and there is no another type of answer expected.

Comment: Are you not using the api version of Rails then?

Comment: I have solved problem with your helpful answer. But reason was another.

Comment: Well, I'm glad it helped though.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is pass HTTP header:

```
headers: {
  "Accept": "application/json"
}
```

it does not require to specify format at controller method with this.
And code:

```
render :show
```

work fine now.

I have commented some code which restrict HTTP headers to request. Answer of @Iceman forwarded me to right direction to check so his answer marked as `answer`.